# How to reset access to Documents folder

Tags: macos, security, parallels-desktop

After installing Parallels Desktop on a system running macOS Catalina, macOS asked if the app can have access to Downloads, Desktop, and Document folders. Permissions were granted. We now want to revoke these permissions. After running the following

```
tccutil reset All
```

macOS asks again whether Parallels can have access to Desktop or Downloads folders (as expected) but it does not ask about the Documents folder and Parallels app continues having access to this folder. Uninstalling and installing again does not help either. What is the proper way of revoking this access.

Just to clarify, this question is about revoking Parallels app access permissions not how to stop sharing Documents folder in VMs.

Comment: does it have full disk access ?

Comment: @ankii no, it doesn't have full disk access. It has never asked for it either.

Comment: Go into System Preferences. Go into Security and Privacy. There is a Privacy Tab, and under that, a list of different modes you can give Applications. Under this list, there should be an option for Documents somewhere. I am not 100% sure about this as I don't have my Mac at this time and am using Windows, but I remember something like this in there somewhere. If this works for you, let me know, and I will enter this as an answer you can accept.

Comment: @Wynter the command mentioned in the question does exactly that (for all services and for all applications). At the moment, the "Files and Folders" in Privacy tab does not have an entry for "Documents folder" under the app, yet the app has full access to Documents folder. It looks like Parallels is somehow circumventing the restriction.

Comment: Strange indeed. I would imagine macOS, with all its security functions (that unfortunately can't be switched off by powerusers like me, lol), would have a simple "Documents" section. But Maybe Documents isn't a protected directory? Or maybe iCloud Documents being on/off has something to do with it? Do you have iCloud Documents turned on?

Comment: @Wynter All the other applications that have requested access to the Documents folder appear in the list and they all have an entry for "Documents Folder" which can be unchecked. Parallels app seems to be able to do this without permission ... or let's I'm unable to revoke the access that was granted earlier.

Comment: @Loax I found this script in some corner of the internet that can be used to completely uninstall parallels. https://pastebin.com/N0UbSf5F

Comment: @ankii Thanks for sharing the script. It does uninstall Parallels Desktop but after reinstallation, Parallels still has access to the Documents folder!